# How to speed up the IMediaControl::Run() when capturing video from a webcam?

Tags: c++, webcam, directshow, video-capture

The code *functions* as intended (using a preview and sample grabber, grabbing and compressing real-time video).  The issue I'm trying to resolve is even on a relatively high-end machine, the actual `Run()` command to start the video streaming can take 4-5 seconds to execute causing an ugly delay in my application... it seems there must be something I can do speed this up.  Following is the code (minus error checking, failure paths, etc.):

```
CoCreateInstance( CLSID_FilterGraph, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC, IID_IGraphBuilder, (void**)&pGraphBuilder );
CoCreateInstance( CLSID_CaptureGraphBuilder2 , NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC, IID_ICaptureGraphBuilder2, (void**)&pCaptureGraphBuilder2 );
pGraphBuilder->QueryInterface( IID_IMediaControl, (LPVOID *) &pMediaControl );

// initialize the capture graph builder
pCaptureGraphBuilder2->SetFiltergraph( pGraphBuilder );  

// get a video window interface for the preview
pGraphBuilder->QueryInterface( IID_IVideoWindow, (LPVOID *) &pVideoWindow );

// get and set the notification parent
pGraphBuilder->QueryInterface( IID_IMediaEventEx, (LPVOID *) &pMediaEventsEx );
pMediaEventsEx->SetNotifyWindow( (OAHWND)msgWindow, WM_GRAPHNOTIFY, 0 );

// pick the camera by the index selected
findCaptureDevice( &pSrcFilter, deviceIndex );

// add Capture filter to our graph
pGraphBuilder->AddFilter( pSrcFilter, L"Video Capture" );

// add in our sample grabber
sampleGrabber.Add( pGraphBuilder );
sampleGrabber.SetMediaType( doOneShot, deviceFormat );
sampleGrabber.SetCallback( this );

// render the preview pin on the video capture filter
pCaptureGraphBuilder2->RenderStream( &PIN_CATEGORY_PREVIEW, &MEDIATYPE_Video, pSrcFilter, sampleGrabber.GetFilter(), NULL );
sampleGrabber.GetMediaType(); // for the dimensions
pSrcFilter->Release();

// set video preview window
setupVideoWindow( previewStatic.m_hWnd );

// 4+ seconds delay here, then everything works fine....
pMediaControl->Run();
```

Any pointers appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

A time consuming `Run` is typically caused by delay in hardware (somewhere on the background of the source filter). Filter graph manager and other filters complete time transition in a fraction of a second. You certainly can do `Pause` well in advance and `Run` might complete faster (a part of delay will move to stopped/paused transition), however if hardware needs so much time to take off you most likely need to start capture ahead of time and skip data in your downstream filter chain. Then at the time you need to start capture you will simply stop ignoring the stream and start of the capture will be instant.

You might also want to check simpler graph Camera Source -> Null Renderer and measure its Run time, to confirm that it's source filter which adds the delay. If source filter starts fast, you will need to isolate the delay to specific filter by incrementally adding filters to the graph.

Comment: A little experimentation showed that requesting capture in RGB24 seems to be the culprit for whatever reason.  I recently started allowing YUY2 input and noticed my delay has nearly gone away except for one camera which does not present YUY2 in its format list.  It does support I420 though so next up will be allowing that format too see if that resolves it...

Comment: Whatever filter graph you ate building, you are always interested to find out the exact topology you end with: Intelligent Connect might add extra filters you don't want. Apparently RGB mode gets you those unwanted filters that add to delay.